# Parsing sql query to JSON

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, typescript

I'm looking for a way, preferable an NPM Package, to parse an SQL query to JSON. I found some for SELECT statements, but I actually need for UPDATE and INSERT INTO statements.
For example, a Query in the form of

```
"UPDATE "users" SET name = $2 where id in ($1)", ['new name', 1]
```

The result should be something like:

```
{ 
  action: 'UPDATE',
  entity: 'users',
  values: { name: 'new name' },
  conditions: { 'id': 1} 
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

There are multiple libraries out there for doing this. One example is [node-sql-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sql-parser). Based on their readme, you can simply do:

```js
const { Parser } = require('node-sql-parser');
const parser = new Parser();
const ast = parser.astify('SELECT * FROM t'); // mysql sql grammer parsed by default

console.log(ast);
```

And the output would be something like this:

```
{
  "type": "select",
  "columns": "*",
  "from": [
    {
      "table": "t"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can play around with it here to see if it matches your expectations: https://npm.runkit.com/node-sql-parser.

Comment: You've been a member long enough to know that questions for off-site resources, like libraries, is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) for SO. Vote to close accordingly instead of adding an opinion-based recommendation.